# Библиотека Discord.py узнать пользователя который отправил команду

Tags: python, бот, discord, discord.py

Доброго времени суток всем! Я начал писать бота и мне нужно сделать так чтобы бот делал примерно такой деалог:
User: !p
Bot: @User hey!
User3: !p
Bot: @User3 hey!
Вот что-то набросал:

```
import discord 
from discord.ext 
import commands 
TOKEN = ':)' 
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!') 
@bot.event 
async def on_ready():
    await print(f"Loaded") 
@bot.command() 
async def test(ctx: commands.Context): 
    await ctx.send("Test") 
@bot.command() 
async def p(ctx: commands.Context):
    await ctx.send(discord.User.id) 
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Но вместо:
User2: !p
Bot: User2
или что-то такое он выводит

> ```
> <member 'id' of 'User' objects>
> ```

Как исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html)
[Information 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4jRhJ7h6B9E&t=591s)
[Information 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XCE4i_fr-K4&t=48s)
[Information 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=giebaN7jE4I) - здесь есть несколько уроков можете посмотреть

```
from discord.ext import commands 
TOKEN = ':)' 
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!') 
@bot.event 
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Loaded") 
@bot.command() 
async def test(ctx: commands.Context): 
      await ctx.send("Test") 
@bot.command() 
async def p(ctx: commands.Context):
      await ctx.send(ctx.user) 
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

У [@xZartsust](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1239669/217579) хороший код, но я нашел более простую и точную альтернативу:

```
@bot.command() 
async def p(ctx):
id = ctx.author.id # Команда ctx.author.id отдельно выделена в библиотеке
                   # discord.py,она и предназначена для 
                   # получения id 
await ctx.send(id)
```